# Split an Array of Json Objects into multiple Arrays In Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, object

I have an Array with multiple json objects that I want to break them into multiple Arrays based on the number of json objects. Each Array should not contain more than 10 objects as an example.

```
[{object-1}, {object-2},....,{object-n}]
Array-1 = [{object-1}, ....,{object-10}]
Array-2 = [{object-11}, ....,{object-21}]
Array-3 = [{object-22}, {object-22}]
```

Looking into the actual Data  note the EventsSelectors Array below. What I am looking for is to extract all the objects in the EventSelectors and breaks them into multiple arrays of EventsSelectors for later processing. Max number of Records should not exceed 20 records.

```
{
    "EventSelectors": [
        {
            "IncludeManagementEvents": true,
            "DataResources": [],
            "ReadWriteType": "All"
        },
        {
            "IncludeManagementEvents": true,
            "DataResources": [],
            "ReadWriteType": "All"
        },
        {
            "IncludeManagementEvents": true,
            "DataResources": [],
            "ReadWriteType": "All"
        }

    ],
    "TrailARN": "arn:aws:cloudtrail:us-east-2:123456789012:trail/TrailName"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: share the actual data (a subset only), explain how the output should look like. share your current effort as well (python code)

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
def slicer(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]


N = 3
data = [{6}, {7}, {8}, {8}, {1}, {2}, {5}, {77}, {88}, {654}]
sliced = {idx: data for idx, data in enumerate(slicer(data, N))}
print(sliced)
```

output

```
{0: [{6}, {7}, {8}], 1: [{8}, {1}, {2}], 2: [{5}, {77}, {88}], 3: [{654}]}
```

Comment: can you add some explanation to your solution

Comment: The 'slicer' is a generator that return (yield) a slice each time is is called. The external loop creates a dict where the key is the index and the value is the slice.

Comment: how can I iterate over the sliced big array. for i in sliced print i something like that.

Comment: The result is a dict. See how can you iterate over a dict ( like a java Map )